# Toggle style tag of div on-click in jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to toggle the style tag of a div element by clicking on another element but the jquery code doesn't seem to work well.. It shows the div but it doesn't hide it!

```
<script>
 $(function() {
  $('.fa.fa-music').click(function() {
   if ($('.musicplay').attr('style'))
    $('.musicplay').removeAttr('style');
   else $('.musicplay').attr({
    style: "visibility: visible; opacity: 1;"
});
});
});
</script>
```

This is the html part

```
<i class="fa fa-music"></i>
<div class="musicplay" style="visibility:hidden;opacity:0;">blablabla</div>
```

Comment: Do you just want to toggle the div's visibility? If so you can do this: $('.fa.fa-music').click(function(e) {e.preventDefault(); $('.musicplay').fadeToggle();})

Comment: generally a lot simpler to toggle a class and have a css rule for the class

Comment: I would avoid using the style attribute and toggle a class instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can set `display` to `none` instead:

```js
$('.fa.fa-music').click(function () {
    if ($('.musicplay').attr('style')) {
        $('.musicplay').removeAttr('style');
    } else {
        $('.musicplay').attr({
            style: "display:none"                                                                 
        });
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<i class="fa fa-music">asdas</i>
<div class="musicplay" style="display: none;">blablabla</div>
```

Same way you can use `visibility`:

```js
$('.fa.fa-music').click(function () {
    if ($('.musicplay').attr('style')) {
        $('.musicplay').removeAttr('style');
    } else {
        $('.musicplay').attr({
            style: "visibility:hidden"                                                                 
        });
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<i class="fa fa-music">asdas</i>
<div class="musicplay" style="visibility: hidden;">blablabla</div>
```

After you comment that you want both `opacity` and `visibility` you can use this:

```js
 $('.fa.fa-music').click(function () {
     if ($('.musicplay').css("visibility") != "hidden") {
         $('.musicplay').attr({
             style: "visibility: hidden; opacity: 0;"
         });
     } else {
         $('.musicplay').attr({
             style: "visibility: visible; opacity: 1;"
         });
     }
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<i class="fa fa-music">asd</i>

<div class="musicplay" style="visibility:hidden;opacity:0;">blablabla</div>
```

Comment: btw I necessarily have to use visibility and opacity because the element has to work even if it is not visible!

Comment: check last snippet please.

Answer (score 0):

Create two css classes and use them:

```
.hidden
{
visibility:hidden;
opacity:0;
}

.visible
{
visibility:visible;
opacity:1;
}

<div class="musicplay hidden" style="">blablabla</div>
```

and now use `addClass()` and `removeClass()`:

```
$('.fa.fa-music').click(function() {
   if ($('.musicplay').hasClass("hidden"))
   {
    $('.musicplay').removeClass("hidden")
    $('.musicplay').addClass("visible")
   }
   else
   {
    $('.musicplay').removeClass("visible")
    $('.musicplay').addClass("hidden")
   }
});
```

### [WORKING EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ev5trbht/)

or you can also use just one class:

```
.hidden
    {
    visibility:hidden;
    opacity:0;
    }
```

and:

```
<div class="musicplay>blablabla</div>
```

and in jquery use `toggleClass()`:

```
$('.fa.fa-music').click(function() {
   $('.musicplay').toggleClass("visible")

});
```

Comment: yes it can be done with one class as well but made with two for clear understanding for OP

Comment: It works very well on jsfiddle.. but it doesn't work on tumblr.. any suggestions? I probably made a mistake omitting that .musicplay is a iframe.. but even with a iframe it works on jsfiddle..!!

Answer (score 0):

Do it by classes:

CSS:

```
.hidden {
   visibility: hidden;
   opacity: 0;
}
```

JS:

```
$('.musicplay').click(function() {
   if($(this).hasClass('hidden') {
      $(this).removeClass('hidden');
   } else {
      $(this).addClass('hidden');
   }
});
```

Remove all style="" attributes and add or remove class hidden from element depends on you want to display or not this element at the beginning.